# Generic Guice Module

Tags: java, kotlin, dependency-injection, guice

Is it possible to define a generic Guice-Module?

I always get a `CreationException`:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) com.example.test.GenericClass<T> cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:470)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:155)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at com.example.test.GenericModuleKt.main(genericModule.kt:23)
    at com.example.test.GenericModuleKt.main(genericModule.kt)
```

This is my example Code:

```kotlin
package com.example.test

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import com.google.inject.Guice
import com.google.inject.Key
import com.google.inject.TypeLiteral

class SomeClass

class GenericClass<T>

class GenericModule<T> : AbstractModule() {
    override fun configure() {
        bind(object : TypeLiteral<GenericClass<T>>(){})
    }
}

fun main() {
    val injector = Guice.createInjector(
        GenericModule<SomeClass>()
    )

    val instance : GenericClass<SomeClass> =
        injector.getInstance(object : Key<GenericClass<SomeClass>>(){})
}
```

EDIT: Working example with the help of Yurii Melnychuk

You need to use `Types.newParameterizedType` to specify the generic class:

```kotlin
class SomeClass

class GenericClass<T>

class GenericModule(
    private val genericClass: Class<*>
) : AbstractModule() {
    override fun configure() {
        val paraType = Types.newParameterizedType(GenericClass::class.java, genericClass)
        bind(TypeLiteral.get(paraType))
    }
}

fun main() {
    val injector = Guice.createInjector(
        GenericModule(SomeClass::class.java)
    )

    val instance : GenericClass<SomeClass> =
        injector.getInstance(object : Key<GenericClass<SomeClass>>(){})
}
```

**If you head into any problem (especially when using generic interfaces) try using Java instead of Kotlin. This solved some problems for me.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic type info is erased at runtime so it is not possible to do what you want the way you do it (at least in Java, Kotlin maybe different in that regard, but I am not familiar with it, maybe reified generics can help).

But from Java perspective I would rather just pass `TypeLiteral`/`Type` to module as constructor argument and bind it (`com.google.inject.util.Types#newParameterizedType` should help).

Comment: Thanks, for your help. I've got my example working. I've added the working code to the question.

Unfortunately, my real life example is a bit more complicated. I have a generic interface that is implemented by that generic class. It seems like I cannot bind a ParameterizedType-Interface to a ParameterizedType-Class. It throws an exception that no implementation is bound for the interface was bound, although that's exactly what I did.

I've added an example to the initial question.

Comment: Update: I seems like this is only an issue when using kotlin. In Java everything works as expected.